# Return sum of Index for matching Array values

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a function in Java which takes two arrays and sums the index values from Array 1 where values match Array 2,  e.g.

- Array1 = {15, 6, 99, 12, 35}
- Array2 = {1, 12, 7, 99, 35}
- Matching "Array1[index]" values = 2 (99), 3 (12), 4 (35)
- So, return 9 (2+3+4)

I would propose doing this using the following:

```
public int sumIndex(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
            if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
                total = total + i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I also want to return -1 if a non-matching value is in Array2. So in the case above 1 and 7 are not in Array1 so that would reduce the total by -2 (-1 for each missing value).

If I add an 'else' statement

```
else {
    total = total - 1;
}
```

or 'else if' statement

```
else if (array1[i] != array2[j]) {
    total = total - 1;
}
```

I get -1 removed from total every time there is a value where array1[index] does not match array2[index] as i and j loop.  I am trying to only return -1 for values in array2 which do not match values in array1.

How would I write this so that total-1 is only returned when a value from array2 is not an element of array1?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I had an issue posting this with code included, I kept getting an error asking that code be formatted using Ctrl+K. Using Ctrl+K did not resolve the issue and prevented me from posting so I added code as images.

Comment: I've re-typed the code sections and the edit has been accepted. Let me know if you have any more questions or comments. Thanks

Comment: Can there be repeating values in _Array 1_ or _Array 2_ ? For example can there be two elements in _Array 1_ with the value 15 ? As in `{15, 6, 99, 12, 15}` Also, would a solution using the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) be acceptable?

Comment: Repeating values can be allowed. No imports allowed. A loop does not have to be used but this is how I was trying to solve it.

Comment: I suggest that you [edit] your question and add an example of an array with repeated values as well as what your expected result should be for such an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your example, I assume that the arrays have unique elements. In such a case, you need to do the following things:

1. Break the inner loop as soon a match is found. This will make your code efficient.
2. Change the order of loops and repeat the same logic.
3. On the termination of the inner loop, check if the inner loop was terminated prematurely (because of `break`). If not, a match was not found and therefore the value of total needs to be decreased by `1`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sumIndex(new int[] { 15, 6, 99, 12, 35 }, new int[] { 1, 12, 7, 99, 35, 100, 1000 }));
    }

    static int sumIndex(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
        int total = 0, i, j;
        // Nested loops to calculate sum of indices having equal values
        for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
                if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
                    total += i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Nested loops to decrease 'total' for the non-matching values of array2
        for (j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
            for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
                if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // If a match is not found, 'i' will reach a value equal to array1.length
            if (i == array1.length) {
                total--;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5
```

Comment: The second if statement will return -1 for all Array1 values that are not found in Array2. Not for any Array2 values not found in Array1.

Comment: @SidheGuido - It doesn't matter if you swap the order to the loops. In any case, what matters is `if (array1[i] == array2[j])`. Did you expect a different result than `7` from the code given above? Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: This is only checking values in Array 1. If you add more int values to Array 2, result is still 7 i.e. if I were to add {100, 1000} to Array 2, result is still 7. If I add {100, 1000} to Array 1, result is 5. I am looking to return -1 if value is in Array 2 but not in Array 1 so I would require total = 5 if {100, 1000} were added to Array 2.

Comment: Ah...now I understand your requirement more clearly...I've updated my answer. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: Required output for these Arrays should be 5. Total = 2+3+4, four values in Array2 not in Array1 (4 x -1): 9 - 4 = 5. I think removing  if (j == array2.length)... might solve this?

Comment: @SidheGuido - Got it. I've updated the answer. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Now I'm wondering if it can be simplified?

Comment: @SidheGuido - I've not found a simpler solution yet; especially when you do not want to use any import. Nevertheless, I'll keep thinking about it and post if I find any simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a flag `found`, reset it every loop, and set it to `true` if `array1[i]` value is found in `array2[j]`, and if it's false reduce `total` by 1.

```
public int sumIndex(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        bool found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
            if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
                total = total + i;
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if(!found)
            total--;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would seem to return -1 for non-matching values from Array1 i.e. if you had two values not contained in Array 1 and one value not contained in Array 2, you would get -2 instead of -1.

Answer (score 0):

You should use lists instead of arrays. If you use lists you can use:

```
List<Integer> arrayList1 = Arrays.asList(15, 6, 99, 12, 35);
List<Integer> arrayList2 = Arrays.asList(1, 12, 7, 99, 35);
int indexSum = 0;
for(Integer integer : arrayList2){
        indexSum = indexSum + arrayList1.indexOf(integer);
}
```

The `indexOf` method returns -1 when the element `integer` of arrayList2 is not present in ArrayList1. If it is present that method will return the index. So if its not present -1 is added to `indexSum`. If it is present the index is added.

Comment: You can use short-circuit operator inside `for` loop, as in: `indexSum += arrayList1.indexOf(integer);`